# Trigger only if build fails

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I'm implementing a deployment/rollback procedure using Jenkins 1.430. I would like to configure the deployment and the rollback steps as 2 separate jobs so as to be triggered independently if needed. However I would also like the rollback to be triggered automatically when the deployment fails.

When I go to the **Post-build Actions** configuration section of the deployment job, I can choose to **Build other projects**. If I check that setting I get 3 options:
**-Trigger only if build succeeds

-Trigger even if the build is unstable

-Trigger even if the build fails**

What I'm missing is the **Trigger only if build fails** option.

Do you know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin,+Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) allows you to run another build of any project based upon the status of the just-completed build.[image]

Comment: I've also found this one: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin